# Setting the token in ngx-admin for connection to Firebase

Tags: angular, rest, firebase, firebase-authentication, token

I am trying to configure my ngx-admin to connect to Firebase using REST API. Most of the posts on Stack Overflow instruct to rewrite the authentication code using Firebase's SDK. This is not what I want. Instead, ngx-admin is already designed to use REST API for authentication, which is also supported by Firebase. I therefore decided to take this approach to use the ngx-admin codebase as much as possible.

My setting under NB_CORE_PROVIDERS in `core.module.ts` is as follows (showing only the login setting for simplicity):

```
providers: {
      email: {
        service: NbEmailPassAuthProvider,
        config: {
          baseEndpoint: 'https://www.googleapis.com/identitytoolkit/v3/relyingparty',
          delay: 3000,
          login: {
            rememberMe: true,
            endpoint: '/verifyPassword?key='+environment.firebase.apiKey,
          },
          // ...
          token: {
            // How to set this properly for Firebase?
          }, 
        },
      },
    },
```

My difficulty is in how to set the token properly for Firebase. The tutorial at https://akveo.github.io/nebular/#/docs/auth/getting-user-token says that

> By default Nebular expects that your token is located under the data.token keys of the JSON response

This translates to the following default setting in `@nebular/auth/providers/email-pass-auth.provider.ts`:

```
token: {
  key: 'data.token',
  getter: (module: string, res: HttpResponse<Object>) => getDeepFromObject(res.body,
        this.getConfigValue('token.key')),
},
```

The tutorial then gives an example which assumes that:

> our API returns a token as just {token: 'some-jwt-token'} not wrapping your response in the data property

and this translates to:

```
token: {
  key: 'token', // this parameter tells Nebular where to look for the token
},
```

First I tried skipping the token setting (which means I use the default, which is `key: 'data.token'`. While I could got a 200 status code (which means I successfully connected to Firebase), I got the following error: `NbEmailPassAuthProvider: Token is not provided under 'data.token' key with getter 'function (module, res) { return Object(__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_9__helpers__["getDeepFromObject"])(res.body, _this.getConfigValue('token.key')); }', check your auth configuration.`

Then I tried `key: 'token'` which gave me a similar error.

Upon consulting the Firebase documentation at https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/auth/#section-sign-in-email-password, I found that the response payload of Firebase consists of six properties: `kind, idToken, email, refreshToken, expliresIn, localId, registered`. I then tried `key: 'idToken'` and this time it worked. I could successfully logged into Firebase. Trying the same for signup also successfully signed me up in Firebase, as I could verify from the Firebase console.

However, this only gets one of the six properties returned. I tried `key: 'data'` instead but it gave me a similar error as above. How can I configure the token key properly so that I can store all the six properties of the token?

Or, should I not attempt to get the other properties but should stick to `idToken` instead? In that case, how could I specify different tokens when the API returns something else in the payload (e.g. when requesting email verification Firebase only returns `kind` and `email` in the payload).

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

try with this:

```
  key: 'idToken'
},
```

it is working for me, with a successful authResult.
**Good Coding;**